# sur fond de Favanaise

Tags: vocabulaire

Please explain "**Favanaise**". An Internet search doesn't do much on this word.
Thanks in advance.  --- tk

C'est un temps de nuits blanches, de discussions dans les bars et les chambres en ville, suivies de caresses déshabillées jusqu'au seuil d'imprudence sur fond de ***Favanaise***. (*Les Années*, Annie Ernaux, pages 87)

Comment: Un genre de musique de l'époque?

Comment: @Frank: Tu as raison! En fait, une chanson de 1963 — [La ***J***avanaise.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Javanaise)

Answer (score 3):

A snippet (from Google books) of the English translation is

> bars, rented rooms in town, caresses on naked skin, on the point of reckless, and the strains of La Javanaise.

So *Favanaise* is a typo for *Javanaise* in your copy of *Les Anneés.*

[La Javanaise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Javanaise) est une chanson de 1963.

Comment: You can strike "it seems". I confirm. Very popular  song in 1963. Amazing a book being published with such a typo.

Comment: @None: I suspect the OP's copy was scanned using optical character recognition, which is a remarkably good way of introducing typos into a book. (This doesn't mean that it's an unauthorized copy; some e-books that you buy are remarkably poorly proofread.)